# Parent Selector Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a class of 'active' to the parent class of an `<li>`

```
   <div id="navigation">
            <ul data-identifier="50dd2c0b-3904-4100-9076-627145a3a949" class=" nav nav-pills  nav-edit " id="nav-main-menu"><li class=" nav-link  dropdown "><a href="/whoweare" data-toggle="dropdown" class=" nav-link  dropdown ">WHO WE ARE <b class="caret"></b></a><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li class=" nav-link  active "><a href="/mission" data-toggle="" class=" nav-link  active ">Mission </a></li><li><a href="/history" data-toggle="" class=" nav-link ">History </a></li><li><a href="/executiveteam" data-toggle="" class=" nav-link ">Executive Team </a></li></ul></li><li class=" nav-link  dropdown "><a href="/greatopportunity" data-toggle="dropdown" class=" nav-link  dropdown ">A GREAT BUSINESS OPPORTUNITY <b class="caret"></b></a><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="/demand" data-toggle="" class=" nav-link ">Demand </a></li><li><a href="/growth" data-toggle="" class=" nav-link ">Growth </a></li><li><a href="/opportunity" data-toggle="" class=" nav-link ">United State Opportunity </a></li><li><a href="/canada_opportunity" data-toggle="" class=" nav-link ">Canada Opportunity </a></li></ul></li><li class=" nav-link  dropdown "><a href="/franchiseeadvantage" data-toggle="dropdown" class=" nav-link  dropdown ">THE FRANCHISEE ADVANTAGE <b class="caret"></b></a><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="/strategy" data-toggle="" class=" nav-link ">Strategy and Tactics </a></li><li><a href="/performance" data-toggle="" class=" nav-link ">Performance Enhancement </a></li><li><a href="/businesstools" data-toggle="" class=" nav-link ">Business Tools </a></li></ul></li><li class=" nav-link  dropdown "><a href="/method" data-toggle="dropdown" class=" nav-link  dropdown ">THE MATHNASIUM METHOD <b class="caret"></b></a><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="/howitworks" data-toggle="" class=" nav-link ">How It Works </a></li></ul></li><li class=" nav-link  dropdown "><a href="/investment" data-toggle="dropdown" class=" nav-link  dropdown ">INVESTMENT <b class="caret"></b></a><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="/unitedstates" data-toggle="" class=" nav-link ">United States / Canada </a></li><li><a href="/international" data-toggle="" class=" nav-link ">International </a></li></ul></li><li class=" nav-link  dropdown "><a href="/meet" data-toggle="dropdown" class=" nav-link  dropdown ">MEET OUR FRANCHISEES <b class="caret"></b></a><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="/testimonials" data-toggle="" class=" nav-link ">Video Testimonials </a></li><li><a href="/writtentestimonials" data-toggle="" class=" nav-link ">Written Testimonials </a></li></ul></li><li><a href="/steps" data-toggle="" class=" nav-link ">STEPS TO OWNERSHIP </a></li><li><a href="/news" data-toggle="" class=" nav-link ">NEWS / PRESS </a></li><li class=" nav-link  dropdown "><a href="/QandA" data-toggle="dropdown" class=" nav-link  dropdown ">Q&amp;A <b class="caret"></b></a><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="/QandA_US-Canada" data-toggle="" class=" nav-link ">United States / Canada </a></li><li><a href="/QandA_international" data-toggle="" class=" nav-link ">International </a></li></ul></li></ul>
            <div id="consumerSite"><br><div style="margin-left:22px">
  <img src="../upload/1/img/cosumerArrow.gif" width="5" height="9" style="margin-right:4px;"><a href="mailto:?subject=A franchising opportunity referral&amp;body=I thought you might be interested in this Mathnasium Learning Center franchising opportunity. To learn more, visit www.mathnasium.com/franchising">Tell a Friend</a><img src="upload/1/img/tellafriend.jpg" width="20" height="11" class="tellafriend"><br><br>



<img src="../upload/1/img/cosumerArrow.gif" width="5" height="9" style="margin-right:4px;"><a href="http://www.mathnasium.com/" target="_blank">Visit our consumer site at<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;www.mathnasium.com</a>
<br>
</div>
</div>
            </div>
```

Javascript:

`jQuery('ul li ul li a').parent('ul li').addClass('active')`;

I'm not sure as to why I can't grab the li that belongs to whoweare.

EDIT: Provided complete section of code. Just trying to add a active class onto the WHO WE ARE

tag.

Comment: [http://api.jquery.com/parent/](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) - maybe you meant parents()

Comment: Why are you traversing to the child and then traversing back to parent? Provide complete code please.

Comment: complete code has been provided

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you should simplify yourself with this:

```
$('ul li').on('click', 'a', function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

---

If you want to add the class `active` on your first `li` in the list, do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul li').first().addClass('active');

    // or select the li with an "a" in it
    $('ul li a').first().parent().addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: I don't want to add the class when I click on the link. I want the class to be there after the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Your outermost `<li>` is not enclosed in a `<ul>`, so the first selector (`"ul li ul li a"`) won't find anything. Use this instead:

```
jQuery('li ul li a')
```

This selects your 3 hyperlinks under your `ul` with class "dropdown-menu". The next problem is with the `parent` method. When you call `parent('ul li')`, that selector is causing jQuery (and myself) some confusion. Simply call `parent()` without any selector, because `parent()` always moves only one level up the DOM tree and stops there. It will automatically select the `<li>` that encloses each `<a>`.

This should do the trick:

```
jQuery('li ul li a').parent().addClass('active')
```

Comment: I added the complete source code above. I forgot to include the UL tag before when I posted my question.